como pasar la versión de un paquete de ubuntu a una variable en script bash
después de buscar en el portal y no encontrar ayuda a mi consulta, paso a preguntar.
deseo obtener la versión de cualquier paquete de los repositorios de Ubuntu desde la versión 22 o 23.
#! /bin/bash
vphp= php -v
echo $vphp
exit 1

lo que realmente me sale es toda la información del mismo php
PHP 8.2.10-2ubuntu1 (cli) (built) .... etc
lo que realmente quiero es que la variable vphp solo quede 8.2
se puede hacer algo así realmente o no?
de antemano, muchas gracias.

El comando vphp= php -v quiere decir "ejecuta el comando php con la opción -v y la variable $vphp definida como vacía en su entorno de ejecución". La manera de asignar valor a variables en bash es var=valor sin espacios. Y lo que querías tu es
vphp=$(php -v)

O el mas viejo y menos potente
vphp=`php -v`

Así se asigna la salida de un comando a una variable. Ahora, php -v tiene mucha información:
$ vphp=$(php -v)

$ echo "$vphp"
PHP 8.3.7 (cli) (built: May  9 2024 14:26:42) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.7, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

Si quieres solo la versión numérica puedes hacer:
$ vphp=$(php -v | head -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f2)
$ echo "$vphp"
8.3.7

Y si solo quieres la version mayor mas menor sin la revisión, puedes usar:
$ vphp=$(php -v | head -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f2 | cut -d. -f1-2)
$ echo "$vphp"
8.3


Aquí yo veo en primer lugar el problema de que no todos los comandos de gnu/linux aceptan el parámetro -v, por lo que yo preguntaría directamente al gestor de paquetes, con "apt policiy".
Por ejemplo:
$ apt policy php
php:
  Instalados: 2:8.3+94+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
  Candidato:  2:8.3+94+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
  Tabla de versión:
 *** 2:8.3+94+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 500
        500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:8.1+92ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ubuntu.cica.es/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ubuntu.cica.es/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages

Con grep podemos quedarnos sólo con la linea de la versión instalada:
$ apt policy php | grep Instalados
  Instalados: 2:8.3+94+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+2

Y con sed podemos usar una expresión regular para borrar todo lo que venga después de un - o un + (ya que apt policy nos puede devolver resultados en ambos formatos):
$ apt policy php | grep Instalados | sed -E 's/[-+].*//'
  Instalados: 2:8.3

Espero que esto te sea de ayuda!

Podrías también quitar el Instalados: con apt policy php | grep Instalados | sed -n 's/[-+].*//; s/.*Instalados: *//p' (no hace falta el -E aquí) y quedarte con el 8.3 como pide la pregunta con  sed -n 's/[-+].*//; s/.*Instalados: *[0-9]*://p'.

Gracias por el aporte. En realidad la pregunta original rezaba "¿se puede hacer algo así realmente o no?", por lo que estrictamente la respuesta correcta sería "Sí"... jajaja, es broma! En mi opinión lo ideal en las respuestas de stackoverflow es que te apunten en la dirección correcta, pero que no sean simplemente de copiar y pegar, donde al final no aprendes nada; pero obviamente es simplemente una opinión personal. Gracias de nuevo, un abrazo.
